# storing XML value to a session variable

Tags: php, session

been trying to store a value from an XML file however it releases an error.

how can i solve this ?

[image]

```
   <?php

session_start();
$success = 0;
session_unset(); 
$clients= simplexml_load_file('client.xml');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($clients -> client_info as $client){ 
            if($_POST['username'] == $client->username && $_POST['pwd'] == $client->pwd ){
              $success = $success + 1;
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $client['id'];

              break;    
            }
        }       
}



if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["id"];
}
else {
    echo "no session";
}
```

thats the code.

however the problem is that when i go outside for example

```
<?php
        session_start();
echo $_SESSION["id"];
?>
```

it says undefined id.

any solutions to this problem?

Comment: oh sorry wait ill edit it

Comment: Are you trying to store the result of simplexml_load_file ($clients) in a session variable? It's not serializable to save it in the session file.

Comment: yes exactly. what does serializable mean or how can I resolve this?

Comment: where is the code with the serialize?

Comment: i just manually created the XML file so i dont know about "serializing" it

Comment: Are you verifying that your loop (foreach) is actually iterating? And also that the conditional inside is evaluation to logic true?

Comment: no, i actually need to store the id of that specific user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save a complete element of the simplexml_load_file() result use the `asXML()` method (formatting the element as XML string). To store the string value of any content element use the `__toString()` method:

Example:

```
$_SESSION["id"] = $client['id']->__toString(); //for attributes
```

---

If you want to save the text content of a xml tag:

```
$_SESSION["clientContent"] = $client->__toString(); //text content of client tag
```

To save an entire xml section as XML string:

```
$_SESSION["client"] = $client->asXML();  //for elements
```

and to restore the $client variable:

```
$client=simplexml_load_string($_SESSION["client"]); //$client as object again
```

Comment: You want `->asXML()` not `->toXML()` http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Comment: Updated using `->asXML()`, added example for storing text content of tag.

Comment: why should i restore it?? i just want to get a value actually

Comment: For the current case, you only need to store the value (1st example)

Comment: what happens when i dont restore it?

Comment: You don't need to restore it. It's saved as string, so the variable can be directly accessed using `$_SESSION['id']` . Restoration is needed if you  save the whole xml object as string and you need to treat it as Object again.